# How should signup form error responses be displayed

Tags: security, authentication, registration, web-application-security

I have a subscription based application that is build using MERN. I've recently submitted the application to be security tested and one of the responses that I received was that the application should not specifically tell the user why their signup application has been rejected for all cases. For example, if they enter a username or email that has already been registered, I shouldn't return an error message that says "Sorry, this username is already registered", as this would allow the user to build a list of users and emails that have registered with our site.

I understand why we need to prevent this, but I don't understand how I can tell the user why there signup submission failed without telling them that it's because that email has already been registered. It seems pointless to reject their signup form without giving them a specific reason, does anyone know what the best thing to do here is?

Comment: What is "MERN"?

Comment: "For example, if they enter a username or email that has already been registered, I shouldn't return an error message that says "Sorry, this username is already registered", as this would allow the user to build a list of users and emails that have registered with our site." <-- Rather than absolutely ruin your UX a better solution is to implement rate-limiting. While hiding e-mail status _can_ be necessary, I don't think hiding username status is useful at all and will just frustrate your users.

Comment: "I've recently submitted the application to be security tested" - can you share any (not necessarily personally-identifiable) details of the _security-people_ that are auditing your application? In my experience most website security "auditors" just run your site through commodity automated vulnerability scanners and e-mail you the PDF along with their inflated invoice.

Comment: Also, **what is your threat-model**? Do you have actionable and/or specific intelligence that you will be targeted by sophisticated malicious agents?

Comment: We dont' really have any high value/risk intelligence, so I doubt we will be targeted to be honest, but always better to be safe than sorry, and we're mostly just fixing some of the smaller issues with our site like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a subscription based application that is build using MERN

The fact you're using MongoDB, Express, React and NodeJS is irrelevant to how your end-users and visitors use your product.

> I've recently submitted the application to be security tested...

*Watch out* - most "security consultants" I've come across that offer to do "analysis" just run some commodity scripts and vulnerability scanners against a website and then lightly touch-up the generated reports to make them look hand-written.

> one of the responses that I received was that the application should not specifically tell the user why their signup application has been rejected for all cases

*Hnnnng* - not in "all" cases, yes - but unfortunately usability and security tend to be opposite ends of a seesaw that you need to carefully balance.

If you're a non-expert or otherwise inexperienced, I'd ask your security-consultant for an exhaustive list of those cases where they consider harmful information-disclosure is possible and then you should run that list by your UX team (and your legal team) to have them weigh-in.

I'll add (if not stress) that the web-application security scene is full of *security-theatre* and cargo-cult-programming practices, and bad and outdated advice sticks around in peoples' heads for too long (e.g. remember how everyone used to insist on changing your password every ~90 days? [not anymore: it turns out that due to human-factors reasons that changing passwords frequently is often *less secure*](https://www.sans.org/blog/time-for-password-expiration-to-die/)).

> For example, if they enter a username or email that has already been registered, I shouldn't return an error message that says "Sorry, this username is already registered", as this would allow the user to build a list of users and emails that have registered with our site.

Before considering any specific scenarios, first consider the nature of your web-application and your threat-model and ask yourself if the damage to the end user-experience is justified by the security gains, or even if there's any actual security gained at all.

For example, and using that issue specifically (i.e. not informing users on the registration page if a username and/or e-mail address is already in-use), I'd argue that for a public Internet website with a general-audience that *usernames* (i.e. login-names, screen-names, etc) are not particularly sensitive, and they're usually mutable, so there is no real end-user harm by disclosing if a username is already taken or not.

...but the existence or details of an e-mail address in your user-accounts database generally *should* not be disclosed to unauthenticated visitors. *However*, I don't think this is really possible to hide from visitors: if someone completes your registration form with completely valid data (excepting an already-in-use e-mail address) and the website rejects the registration attempt with a vague or completely useless error message then a novice user is going to be frustrated and give-up (and think your website is *just broken*), while a malicious user (with even a basic knowledge of how web-applications work) is going to instantly know it's because the e-mail address is in-use because it will work when they submit a different e-mail address - ergo: you haven't actually gained any security benefit while simultaneously losing business because your registration process is made painfully difficult.

However, consider *alternative approaches*:

One possible alternative approach for this problem specifically is to *make it appear* that the registration was successful, but to not let the malicious user in until they verify the e-mail address via emailed link (which they won't be able to do if it isn't their address), and if it is just a novice-user who is already registered and didn't realise it then just send them an email reminding them of that fact. This approach might be preferable on a social-media site where it's important to not disclose anything relating to any other users' PII - but this approach probably wouldn't be appropriate for a line-of-business system.

Another alternative approach: *don't have your own registration system*: just use OIDC and let users authenticate and register via Google, Facebook, Apple, etc. This also saves your users from having to remember another password.

As for the risk of information-harvesting: I appreciate that bots that brute-force large amounts of form-submissions sounds like a good match for never revealing information, a better solution is to just add a CAPTCHA and to rate-limit clients (both by limiting total requests-per-hour as well as adding artificial delays to user registration processing (e.g. humans generally don't care if a registration form POST takes 500ms or 1500ms, but that 1000ms difference will drastically affect bots.

In all my time building web-applications, I've never encountered any serious attempts at information-harvesting via automated registration form or login form submissions: it's always just marketing spam, and adding a CAPTCHA (even without rate-limiting) was all that was needed to put an end to that.

(The "non-serious" attempts at information-harvesting that I *have seen* were things like [non-technical](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/oh-god-how-did-this-get-here-i-am-not-good-with-computer) human-users manually "brute-forcing" themselves by typing through their keyboard: they all give-up after a few dozen attempts).

> I understand why we need to prevent this, but I don't understand how I can tell the user why there signup submission failed without telling them that it's because that email has already been registered. It seems pointless to reject their signup form without giving them a specific reason, does anyone know what the best thing to do here is?

I'm getting the feeling maybe you got scammed by your security "consultants" making-up overstated risks in their report to you - rather than your web-application actually being at risk of being exploited.

Comment: Thanks Dai, I really appreciate your response and the detail you went into to explain my best options. To be clear, the security report we received was from an affiliate's security checks and so we didn't pay for it. This is one of the most basic flaws they found in our app, and they did identify some other more complex issues that were helpful to us. I think adding captcha , rate limits and then using the email verification method as you detailed it is probably my best option here. I'll work on doing these things and hopefully they deem this sufficient for their security tests.